# Props History push, después de insertar un registro

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un formulario el cual usa una API (funciona correctamente), pero, estoy tratando de direccionar después del aviso (ver el switch case en el código "Registro guardado") inserta correctamente pero no me redirecciona a la página que deseo que lleve al usuario. Ya intente con vario métodos, usando el Link, Route y no lo hace. Y lo ultimo que intenté fue con el: this.props.history.push(), y marca este error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
at Insertar-enfermedades.js:53:1

Código de .js:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link  } from "react-router-dom";

class Insertarenfermedades extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    state = { 
        txtnombreenf:"",
        txtdescripenf:""
     }

     cambiodeValor=(e)=>{
        const state=this.state;
        state[e.target.name]=e.target.value;
        this.setState({state});
     }

    enviarDatos = (e) =>{
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log("Enviando datos");
          const {txtnombreenf, txtdescripenf}=this.state;
          console.log(txtnombreenf);
          console.log(txtdescripenf);          

          try {                   
                    var datosEnviar={Nombre_enf:txtnombreenf, Descrip:txtdescripenf}

                    fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Enfermedades/Sp_Insert_Enfermedades.php",{
                           method:"POST",
                           body:JSON.stringify(datosEnviar)
                    })
                    .then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())
                    .then((datosRespuesta)=>{                           
                          switch (datosRespuesta) {
                            case "No insertado, porque están nulos los datos":
                                alert(datosRespuesta);
                            break;

                            case "No insertado, porque ya existe":
                                alert(datosRespuesta);
                            break;                         
                            
                            case "Registro guardado":
                                
                                alert(datosRespuesta,  this.props.history.push("/listarenf")); 
                                this.props.history.push("/listarenf");                  
                            break;
                          }
                     }
                    )
                    .catch(console.log)
                 
          } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
          }
    }   
    render() { 
        const {txtnombreenf, txtdescripenf}=this.state;  

        return ( 
             <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header">
                    Agregar Enfermedades
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <form onSubmit={this.enviarDatos}>                      
                                <div className="form-group">
                                     <label htmlFor="">Nombre de la enfermedad:</label>
                                     <input type="text" onChange={this.cambiodeValor} value={txtnombreenf}  name="txtnombreenf" id="txtnombreenf" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea el nombre de la enfermedad" ></input>
                                     
                                </div>
                                 
                                <div className="form-group">
                                     <label htmlFor="">Descripción de la enfermedad:</label>
                                     <input type="text" onChange={this.cambiodeValor} value={txtdescripenf} name="txtdescripenf" id="txtdescripenf" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea Descripción de la enfermedad" ></input>
                                     
                                </div>
                          
                                <div className="input-group">
                                    <span className="input-group-btn">                                        
                                        <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit" aria-label="">Guardar</button>
                                        <Link to={"/listarenf"} className="btn btn-danger" type="button" aria-label="">Cancelar</Link>
                                        <Link to={"/listarenf"} className="btn btn-warning" type="button" aria-label="">Regresar al Listado</Link>
                                   </span>                                    
                                 </div>                              
                    </form>                             
                </div>                
             </div>
         );
    }
} 
export default Insertarenfermedades;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En React router v6 `useHistory` es reemplazado por `useNavigate`

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/home');
```

Answer (score 0):

Y si tratas de desestructurar props antes de realizar el request?

```
const { history } = this.props

try {
   fetch(...)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
       switch(condicion) {
          case 'Registro guardado': {
             history.push(ruta)
          }
       }
    })
} catch (error) {
   console.log(error)
}
```

**[Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243931/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-history-on-react-js)** te dejo la fuente

Comment: Hola. Deja verifico y te comento.

Comment: No. No funciono :-/. No entiendo. He seguido estos ejemplos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pG8VboW8iE&ab_channel=ReactDeveloper y también lo que me pasaste, pero, no entiendo porque no funciona.

Comment: También use: cancelCourse = () => { 
          //document.getElementById("webFrmInsertarEnf").reset();
          this.setState({
               txtnombreenf: "",
               txtdescripenf: "" 
                               
            }); 
             redirect("/listarenf");
          }  Y nada... No lo manda a la página que quiero.